# Add Get Variable (QueryString) into PostBackUrl in FormView asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have following code:

```
<asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Add Form" 
             PostBackUrl="~/APPLICATION/FormView.aspx?postquestion="/>
```

I using FormView Control.

I need to add Request.QueryString["postquestion"] variable into "FormView.aspx?postquestion=" for PostBackUrl.

I found following code on net, however it's not working:

```
PostBackUrl='<%# ="~/APPLICATION/FormView.aspx?postquestion=" + Request.QueryString  ["postquestion"].ToString() %>'
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what is happening?  Are there any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning the `PostBackUrl` like this instead:

```
<asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" 
    CausesValidation="True" 
    CommandName="Insert" 
    Text="Add Form"          
    PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format("~/APPLICATION/FormView.aspx?postquestion={0}", Request.QueryString["postquestion"]) %>' />
```

Comment: @user1202420: No problem! Don't forget to mark the answer if you're satisfied :-)